# Why are highly-voted "(not an) answer"s not converted to comments?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

If something appearing like "**not an answer**", is written by a high-rep user or has been highly voted (>= 3), then it's getting less likely to get converted as comment or deleted. In past, I have flagged many such answers only to get the flag being rejected. Recent examples:

- [Difference between "string" and
  "string.h"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257684/514235) -- "disputed"
- [Why can the return type of main not be
  deduced?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39107127/514235) -- "found no
  evidence"
- [Priority of C++ operators “&” and
  “->”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154820/514235) -- "found no
  evidence"

However such answers have been easily deleted in certain situations. Is my flagging wrong here or the high rep answers are psychologically locked for "converting to comment" or "deletion"?

**Update**: I understand that, downvote should be used for wrong or bad answers. My main point is to improve the quality of the site. Will we like to see more such answers as the above 3? These 3 answers are suited for a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 15):

Those 3 answers you linked are, in fact, answers.
They attempt to answer the question, and from what I can see, they do.

That's why a "NAA" flag is invalidated on those. It's got nothing to do with the votes they received.
Sure, the may be short, but "Low quality" isn't a reason to flag a answer.

Comment: How will be SO, if all its answers looked like those 3? Mod should at least act on them for quality basis.

Comment: @iammilind `How will be SO, if all its answers looked like those 3?` they don’t, though, do they? The third answer you link to is from 2008. It wouldn’t have a chance these days. The other two are clearly answers, and other than that they’re really short I don’t see what the quality problems are that you’re talking about. If you don’t like them, vote them down

Comment: @iammilind I think that blaming the questions that foment these kind of answers is more productive... how about if SO was filled with those kind of questions...? I'm not even sure that's part of the nightmare we are living through

Answer (score 1):

> My main point is to improve the quality of the site. Will we like to see more such answers as the above 3?

Let's say that I agree with you. That these answers are not good answers, and we want to discourage such answers.

The fact that they're not good answers does not mean that they are *not answers* at all. They're just not *good* answers.

We have a tool for dealing with "not good answers"; it's called "downvoting". We remove answers which are not answers or otherwise violate the rules of the site. We don't remove answers because of their *quality*.